# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm trying to create a Note taker app, but when click on save any information, is coming a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')`

Below the code for Note.js

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const uniqid = require('uniqid');

let noteList = [];

function findById(id, noteList) {
    return noteList.filter(note => note.id === id)[0];
}

function addNewNote(body, noteList) {
    let newNote = body;
    newNote.id = uniqid();
    noteList.push(newNote);
    fs.writeFileSync(
        path.join(__dirname, '../db/db.json'),
        JSON.stringify({db: noteList}, null, 2)
    );
    return newNote;
}

function removeNote (id, noteList) {
    const removeThisNote = findById(id, noteList);
    for (let i = 0; i<noteList.length; i++){
        if (noteList[i].id === removeThisNote.id) {
            noteList.splice(i, 1);
            fs.writeFileSync(
                path.join(__dirname, '../db/db.json'),
                JSON.stringify({db: noteList}, null, 2)
            );
        }
    };
}

module.exports = {
    findById,
    addNewNote,
    removeNote
};
```

api **index.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const {db} = require('../db/db.json');
const { addNewNote, removeNote} = require('../lib/note.js');


router.get('/notes', (req, res) => {
    let results = db;
    res.json(results);
})

router.post('/notes', (req, res) => {
    const newNote = addNewNote(req.body, db);
    res.json(newNote);
})

router.delete('/notes/:id', (req, res) => {
    removeNote(req.params.id, db);
    res.json(req.body);
})

module.exports = router;
```

**Server.js**

```
const express = require(`express`);
const apiRoutes = require('./routes/apiRoutes.js');
const path = require('path');
// const htmlRoutes = require('./routes/htmlRoutes.js');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use('/api', apiRoutes)
// app.use('/', htmlRoutes)

app.use(express.static(`public`));

//Routes
app.get(`/notes`, (req, res) => {
  console.log(`Note page requested`);
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, `public/notes.html`));
});

app.get(`/`, (req, res) => {
  console.log(`Home page requested`);
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, `public/index.html`));
});

app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
);
```

Can anyone help with this ?

I want to deploy this using Heroku but when testing save any info, error comes up.

Comment: What debugging have you undertaken? What is the value/type of `db` that you're passing into that function, and trying to add things to?

Comment: Unrelated: the `noteList` array in `Note.js` is deceptive since it's not actually used anywhere. No clue what `db` is.

Comment: The error means that the `noteList` parameter in `addNewNote()` is `undefined`.

Comment: Pointing the same that other comments. Please make sure what are you importing in the db constant at index.js. Is it possible that this require is pointing to a constant that doesn't exist? Try to do a console.log of db in router.get callback's body

Comment: Is that the full error you're getting? If not, can you edit your question to include the full error?

Comment: Where have you defined body? Do you mean to set newNote to document.body?

Answer (score 0):

`push()` is an Array method. Therefore, the error shows that some variable is not array but undefined.

The `addNewNote` function contains a variable called `noteList` and the error says it is not an array.
So, the argument you pass to this function is not an array.

I suggest you check the `db` variable you import from `db.json` and see if this is an array because this is the variable you pass as an argument in `addNewNote`.